# Auto-link Github PR to issue and close issue when PR gets merged

Tags: github, github-actions

When I create a branch from an issue (like the below image) and then create a PR from that branch to `main` branch, I expect the PR to be linked to that issue and close the issue when the PR gets merged. But, unfortunately, that's not happening.

[image]

Github [says](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue#about-linked-issues-and-pull-requests), I can link a PR to an issue using a supported keyword in the pull request description like `Closes #10` (issue number). Is there a way to avoid this manual step because the branch with PR is already linked to the issue?

Comment: I don't believe there is: GItHub currently merely create a Git branch in the Git repository without doing anything special in their GitHub-only PR section. You'd have to have GitHub do that; PRs are not part of Git (though branch names are).

Answer (score 0):

When you make a branch directly from the issue when a PR is opened with that branch it will automatically be linked. And I just tested this out and it should be working.

It says in the GH docs:

> Branches connected to an issue are shown under the "Development" section in the sidebar of an issue. When you create a pull request for one of these branches, it is automatically linked to the issue. The connection with that branch is removed and only the pull request is shown in the "Development" section. For more information, see "[Linking a pull request to an issue](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue)."

The above quote is from [this help article](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/creating-a-branch-for-an-issue#about-branches-connected-to-an-issue).

Comment: I wish it was happening but that's not the case, unfortunately. For example,  [this pr](https://github.com/GorvGoyl/Notion-Boost-browser-extension/pull/125) should automatically be linked to [this issue](https://github.com/GorvGoyl/Notion-Boost-browser-extension/issues/124) but it's not. I had to mention issuenumber to link the issue

Comment: @GorvGoyl did you don't from the GH UI?

Comment: didn't get what you're asking

Comment: @GorvGoyl did you ever figure out what was happening? We are encountering this issue of PR not automatically back linking to the issue in *one* repo, while another repo works as expected… :-|